# Killing Lie algebra action on Lie algebra valued forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let and $P$ a $G$-bundle with a Riemannian base space $(M,g)$. Denote $\mathfrak{h}$ the Lie subalgebra formed by the Killing vector fields within the vector fields of $M$. This subalgebra acts on the space of vector fields via the adjoint representation. I would like to know if there is natural representation of $\mathfrak{h}$ over the space $\Omega^1(M, \mathfrak{g})$ of Lie algebra valued forms.

Answer (score 1):

Sure: the entire Lie algebra of vector fields acts on forms and so vector-valued forms and, in particular, $\mathfrak{g}$-valued forms.  Now restrict this action to $\mathfrak{h}$.

However, yr principal bundle $P$ plays absolutely no role at all in this so I suspect I am not answering the question you really meant to ask.

Comment: Perhaps by $\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak{g})$ the OP means $\Omega^1(M,\operatorname{ad}P)$?

Comment: Perhaps, José.  But then the answer to the question is surely no unless $P$ is somehow tied to the Riemannian structure of the base...